# Unable to get the geolocation on macos using jxbrowser in java swing application

Tags: java, macos, desktop-application, desktop, jxbrowser

I am using jxbrowser to integrate google maps in my java swing application on macos . But due to permission restriction I am not able to get the geolocation requested by the google maps . Below is my code .

```
Engine browserEngine = Engine.newInstance(EngineOptions.newBuilder(RenderingMode.HARDWARE_ACCELERATED)
        .enableProprietaryFeature(ProprietaryFeature.WIDEVINE)
        .enableProprietaryFeature(ProprietaryFeature.AAC)
        .enableProprietaryFeature(ProprietaryFeature.H_264)
        .googleApiKey("api-key")
        .googleDefaultClientId("client-id")
        .googleDefaultClientSecret("client-secret-id")
        .licenseKey("jxbrowser license key")
        .remoteDebuggingPort(9222)
        .build());

        browserEngine.permissions().set(RequestPermissionCallback.class, (params, tell) -> {
            PermissionType type = params.permissionType();
            System.out.println("Permission type is :"+type);
            if (type == PermissionType.VIDEO_CAPTURE || type == PermissionType.AUDIO_CAPTURE) {
                tell.grant();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Permission type is :"+type);
                tell.grant();
                System.out.println("Permission granted");

            }
        });

        Browser browser = browserEngine.newBrowser();
        browser.navigation().loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMI

ZED_BOTH);
        frame.add(BrowserView.newInstance(browser));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

I need to solve this issue as soon as possible, I am stuck in this issue.

I just need to access the location , but i am not able to get the geolocation on macos . Same code is working well on windows .

Comment: The code itself is totally fine. The problem lies in the area of macOS permissions. JxBrowser launches Chromium in a separate process, so you may need to grant Chromium necessary permissions.